# Mapping 2 USB devices to defined path

Tags: linux, serial-port, mapping, usb

I've listed my USB devices to their serial ports by searching for them.

```
ls -l /dev/ttyACM*
```

However as I plug and unplug the USB devices (Conbee II & Z-Stick Gen 5+) they swap ports causing my containers to crash as I restart.

Any way to map these to a specific path?

I tried to set the variables inside the container to be mapped to the specific devices as I list them with the `ls` command. After I do so, they tend to swap around however.

Comment: Make udev rule to create symlinks, distinguish your devices by their attributes (and USB port path if needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `/dev/ttyACM*`, use the symbolic links that the kernel creates for you in `/dev/serial/by-id`.